# Check if object in list has specific field content

Tags: c#, list

Sorry for question title, I don't know really how to explain it in a single sentence...

I have a class like this

```
public class xyz
{
    public static string attr1;
    public static string attr2;
    public static string attr3;
}
```

how can i check if there is an object with attr1=="aaa" in a `List<xyz>`?

is there something like

```
List<xyz> MyList = new List<xyz>();

[...]

bool attr1_exist = MyList.attr1.Contains("aaa");
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this should do it:

```
bool attr1_exist = MyList.Exists(s=> s.attr1 == "aaa")
```

Comment: thanks! but what's the difference between using .Any or .Exists?

Comment: Both are effectively the same method, .Any() is available from .net 3.5 and upwards. I work with .net 2.0 so suggested Exists() from habit I guess. Maybe @DGibbs could suggest why he used .Any?

Comment: @MichaelB Pretty much the same reason, I use newer versions of the framework though. `Any()` is slightly different in that it can be used without a lambda e.g. `MyList.Any()` will return true if the list has any items, other than that, they are essentially the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
bool attr1_exist = MyList.Any(x => x.attr1.Contains("aaa"));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following Code:**

```
Boolean IsExist = MyList.Any(n=> n.attr1 == "aaa");
```

**OR**

```
if(MyList.Where(n=> n.attr1 == "aaa").Count() > 0)
{
    //Do Somthing . . .
}
```